# "Selected" style for WinAPI toolbar button?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Is there a way to make a toolbar button look different than the rest (Aside from changing bitmap or setting its state to Disable? Is there away to make it look highlighted all the time? I want the selected tool to look selected. Thanks (Sort of like the way open applications are "Selected" in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the TB_SETHOTITEM message